# Why in a try catch finally, the return is always that of finally?

Tags: java

What happens to the `return A` code in my catch block?

```
public class TryCatchFinallyTest {

    @Test
    public void test_FinallyInvocation()
    {
        String returnString = this.returnString();
        assertEquals("B", returnString);
    }

    String returnString()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("");
        }
        catch (RuntimeException bogus)
        {
            System.out.println("A");
            return "A";
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("B");
            return "B";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lots of answers on here already. Here's the most relevant section in the JLS I can find: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2. This spells out that if the catch block completes successfully, then the finally block is executed. After running a sample myself and reading that section, this leads me to believe that the return statement of the catch block is discarded in this case.

Comment: Of course, you could be asking about the details of what the JVM implementation does explicitly, rather than the behavior that the JVM should exhibit. Could you clarify what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The finally get's executed right before any return's / exits from the method. Therefore, when you do

```
return "A";
```

it executes like so:

```
System.out.println("B");//Finally block
return "B";//Finally block
return "A";//Return from exception catch
```

And thus the "B" is returned, not the "A"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `return "A";` is optimized away by the compiler, maybe not and "A" is just dynamically replaced. In fact it doesn't matter as you should not have this code.

This is one of the classical examples of problems with using finally for control flows : you lose some instructions and another coder might not see the "intent" (in fact it can only be a bug or a mischief).

You may have noted that javac issues a warning *"finally block does not complete normally"*.

**[Don't return in a finally clause](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/staufferjames/archive/2007/06/_dont_return_in.html)**

Answer (score 0):

the finally block will always be executed, while the catch block is only executed if there's an exception caught.

Answer (score 0):

Before `return "A"` , `finally` block would be called which will `return "B"` and your `return "A"` would be skipped and would never be executed. Its because `finally` block is always executed before `return` statement of the method, and if you are returning something from `finally` block then the `return` statement of your `try/catch` would always skipped.

Note : Returning from `finally` block is not a good practice for a Java programmer. JAVA Compiler also show you the warning as "**finally block does not complete normally**" if you are returning something from `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

Finally

You can attach a finally-clause to a try-catch block. The code inside the finally clause will always be executed, even if an exception is thrown from within the try or catch block. If your code has a return statement inside the try or catch block, the code inside the finally-block will get executed before returning from the method.

References http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html

Comment: This citation doesn't make it really clear that the returned statement taken into account is the one of the finally block.

Comment: Look at the last line, the finally block will be executed before returning. So when the return statement found it will call the finally block which actually return.